# Calling services from the Orchestrating layer in SOA?

Tags: architecture, soa, composition, loose-coupling, reusability

The Service Oriented Architecture Principles [site](http://soaprinciples.com/) says that Service Composition is an important thing in SOA. But Service Loose Coupling is important as well.

Does that mean that the "Orchestrating layer" should be the only one that is allowed to make calls to services in the system?

As I understand SOA, the "Orchestrating layer" 'glues' all the services together into one software application. I tried to depict that on Fig.A and Fig.B.

The difference between the two is that on Fig.A the application is composed of services and all the logic is done in the "Orchestrating layer" (all calls to services are done from the "Orchestrating layer" only). On Fig.B the application is composed from services, but one service calls another service.

Does the architecture on Fig.B violate the "Service Loose Coupling" principle of SOA? Can a service call another service in SOA? And more generally, can the architecture on Fig.A be considered superior to the one on Fig.B in terms of service loose coupling, abstraction, reusability, autonomy, etc.?

My guess is that the A architecture is much more universal, but it can add some unnecessary data transfers between the "Orchestrating layer" and all the called services.

[image: SOA service calls]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything below services 1 and 2 is encapsulated behind their contracts then they are loosely coupled.  However B does not leverage the orchestration layer's ability to free up Service 1.  There is no clear right or wrong of A vs B but there are trade-offs.  Fig A requires some more development effort because details of what B returns to A need to extracted up to the orchestration layer - and if there are lists of data involved then B needs to allow a collection of parameters to be passed in as criteria.  This however allows svc 1 to know nothing about svc 2.  So if the services are owned and managed by two different teams then A is going to allow these team to work autonomously.  For example, if svc 1 is a customer information service (CIS) and svc 2 is a payments service then the orchestration layer can stitch CIS data together with Svc 2 to return a list of customer names and their most recent payment data.  With Fig A an in-memory join is used in the orchestration layer to do the stitching.  Then clients call the orchestration layer.  With B the client can call directly into service 1, but if you start to allow services to call into each other you can end up with a nasty dependency graph including the possibility for re-entrant calls.  If your team is small and owns both svc 1 & 2 then they can track these dependencies.  However when you have different teams you might find the dependencies are not easily known or well managed in B.

Comment: Has your return key broken?